# Issue with CABasicAnimation

Tags: swift, cabasicanimation

So basically I am trying to create dialogView. This dialogView will contain a loading spinner and some text which will be updated depending on the state. I followed two guides to use a CAShapeLayer to draw a circle and then animate a line around it.

Link to code/guides I followed
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3ltwjDJaMk
https://github.com/vinayjn/Spinner/blob/master/Spinner.swift

Despite following most of these tutorials to the tee. My animation will not work. At the moment it just looks like this and will not spin.

[image]

```
class LoginDialogView: UIViewController {
    lazy var loaderView: UIView = {
        let loaderView = UIView()
        loaderView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return loaderView
    }()

    lazy var dialogTitle : UILabel = {
        let dialogTitle = UILabel()
        dialogTitle.text = "Apples"
        dialogTitle.font =  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24.0)
        dialogTitle.textAlignment = .left
        dialogTitle.numberOfLines = 1
        return dialogTitle
    }()

    private var shouldAddSublayer: Bool {
           /*
            check if:
            1. we have any sublayers at all, if we don't then its safe to add a new, so return true
            2. if there are sublayers, see if "our" layer is there, if it is not, return true
           */
           guard let sublayers = loaderView.layer.sublayers else { return true }
           return sublayers.filter({ $0.name == "progress"}).count == 0
       }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupView()
    }
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        if shouldAddSublayer {
            setupCircleLayers()
        }
    }

    fileprivate func setupView() {
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 20

        view.addSubview(loaderView)
        loaderView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top).offset(10)
            make.centerX.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.centerX)
            make.height.width.equalTo(100)
        }
    }

    private func setupCircleLayers() {
        let trackLayer = createCircleShapeLayer(strokeColor: UIColor.init(red: 56/255, green: 25/255, blue: 49/255, alpha: 1), fillColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9686274529, green: 0.78039217, blue: 0.3450980484, alpha: 1))
        loaderView.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
        startAnimating()
    }

    private func startAnimating(){
        animateRing()
    }

    private func animateRing(){
        let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0 * (CGFloat.pi / 180)
        rotationAnimation.toValue = 360 * (CGFloat.pi / 180)
        rotationAnimation.duration = 1.6
        rotationAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE
        loaderView.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: "strokeEnd")
    }

    private func createCircleShapeLayer(strokeColor: UIColor, fillColor: UIColor) -> CAShapeLayer {
        let centerpoint = CGPoint.zero
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerpoint, radius: 30, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        layer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
        layer.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor
        layer.strokeStart = 0
        layer.strokeEnd = 0.5
        layer.lineCap = .round
        layer.lineWidth = 5
        layer.position = CGPoint(x: loaderView.frame.size.width / 2, y: loaderView.frame.size.height / 2)
        layer.name = "progress"
        return layer
    }

}
```

I have looked over and compared the code a couple times and I can't see what I did that was different. So my question is can anyone look over this code and figure out what I did wrong? and Can anyone recommend a safe way to stop this animation that wouldn't cause any potential memory leaks?

Im using ios 13 and xcode 11.3.1

Comment: `0 * (CGFloat.pi / 180)` is pointless. The result will always be zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding the animation to the shape layer; you added it to the container view's layer. Keep a reference to your `trackLayer` and add the animation to that layer.

```
class LoginDialogView: UIViewController {
    lazy var loaderView: UIView = {
        let loaderView = UIView()
        loaderView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return loaderView
    }()

    var trackLayer: CAShapeLayer?

    ...
    ...
    ...

    private func setupCircleLayers() {
        trackLayer = createCircleShapeLayer(strokeColor: UIColor(red: 56/255,
                                                                 green: 25/255,
                                                                 blue: 49/255,
                                                                 alpha: 1),
                                            fillColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9686274529, green: 0.78039217, blue: 0.3450980484, alpha: 1))
        loaderView.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer!)
        startAnimating()
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...

    private func animateRing(){
        let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0 * (CGFloat.pi / 180)
        rotationAnimation.toValue = 360 * (CGFloat.pi / 180)
        rotationAnimation.duration = 1.6
        rotationAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE
        trackLayer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: "strokeEnd")
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Note: ... in the above code refers to the truncated portion of your code.

Comment: could i maybe ask one more question ?

Comment: `0 * (CGFloat.pi / 180)` is pointless. The result will always be zero

Comment: @Sandeep what do you mean